# Rails validation on insert vs create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model where the validity of a record is dependant on what other records exist at the time of insertion.

Whilst not exactly the same scenario, let's imagine I have an AuctionBid model - a bid in it's own right is valid (has a user, value, currency whatever) and I want Rails to tell me that this is the case.

However, when I come to insert the bid into the database and find that some of the other records are larger bids I now want the record to be invalid and not save.

Using:

```rb
validates :bid_is_valid, on: :create
```

doesn't quite do this as it validates the record as if it's being inserted.  How can I have the validation only run on insertion?  Do I need a `before_save` or something that stops the insertion over a validation?

Comment: `if: :new_record?` ?

Comment: Or you need some database layer `CHECK` constraint to exclude race condition? Question looks unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

Rails **validations** are application side and are performed before an INSERT or UPDATE query is attempted. They are just callbacks that are fired before certain lifecycle events and add errors to the errors object and thus prevent saving/updating.

Validations don't actually guarentee the integrity of the database data and are easily circumvented. They simply prevent invalid data from slipping through **most of the time** resulting in invalid data and give the user feedback about what's wrong with the query.

One common example of this is the uniqueness validation which is very prone to race conditions.

Guarenteeing the actual integrity of the data is done on the database side with **constraints**. Rails 6.1 added a convenient check_constraint method to add constraints in migrations (without using a raw SQL string).

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :price
      t.check_constraint "price_check", "price > 100" 
    end
  end
end
```

Note that if the integrity of the data is important you want both validations and constraints. The validation will still catch most of the bad input and prevent it from escalating into a database driver error.